# Good sound apis for linux?

Tags: c++, linux, directsound

I am learning game development and came across this playlist(Handmade Hero) about making a game from absolute scratch, like using only Os provided apis. The series focuses on windows, I also want to develope the same thing for linux. What should be the sound api that I should use? In the series he was using DirectSound, what would be the similar kind of api for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ALSA](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page) (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture)

- part of the linux kernel (sound drivers)
- user space library ([alsa-lib](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/))

There are also so called sound servers available on linux, like [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/) or [pipewire](https://pipewire.org/).

Frameworks for game development

- [SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAudio)
- [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/)